# How do I use 'sed' to read a line from txt?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to use a variable (the day of the year out of 365 using +%j) to search a txt file, using that variable to find the line number.

I can't figure out how to substitute '1p' below to something like.. "$dat + p" or something like that. Nothing I am thinking of or finding online is working, I am thinking I just am not coming up with good enough search terms to figure this thing out.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
dat= date +%j

arg=$(cat /home/adam/dailyverses.txt | sed -n '1p')

echo $arg
```

Comment: `test "$n" -ge 0 && sed -n "${n}p" /home/adam/dailyverses.txt`

Comment: Try `sed -n $(date +%j)p  /home/adam/dailyverses.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to catch the output of the `date` command this way:

```
dat="$(date +%j)"
```

Or this way when you need to comply with an old shell:

```
dat=`date "+%j"`
```

> I am trying to use a variable (the day of the year out of 365 using +%j) to search a txt file, using that variable to find the line number.

So I think `sed` is not the right tool. Trying to make a substitution is not the right way.

Searching a pattern and getting the line number which match this pattern: `grep` would be the perfect fit! For example:

```
grep -nE "^.*${dat}.*$" /home/adam/dailyverses.txt|cut -d: -f1
```

You can also do it using `bash`:

```
line_number=1
while read -r; do
  [[ $REPLY =~ ^.*${dat}.*$ ]] && echo "${line_number}"
  (( line_number++ ))
done < "/home/adam/dailyverses.txt"
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {count = 1} {count++; if($0 ~ "^.*'"${dat}"'.*$"){print count}}' "/home/adam/dailyverses.txt"
```

Of course you can change the regexp according to your needs.

> I can't figure out how to substitute '1p' below to something like.. "$dat + p" or something like that.

That's not really the same thing than just "find the line number" like you asked before. But if it's what's you really want:

```
dat="$(date +%j)"
sed -n "${dat}p" /home/adam/dailyverses.txt
```

Comment: `$()` has been standard since sometime in the mid 90s.  Certainly it's from the last millennium.   There is no need for backticks, except as a formatting device in SO comments.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I prefer to show both ways (backsticks are still valid and not officially deprecated, lots of "old" sysadmins and programers still consider it as a good practice even if I disagree but I prefer to show some form of exhaustivity in my answers).

Comment: That is a reasonable position to take, but it doesn't make sense to say that backticks should be used if the author is seeking POSIX compliance. `$()` is POSIX compliant, and indeed recommended.  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03

Comment: @WilliamPursell I've updated my answer "a POSIX shell" => "an old POSIX shell" (because it depends on the version of POSIX and the existence of some old Unix which are still alive even if it's get rarer over the years). Anyway I agree that nowadays, `$()` should be the standard and common way to write it. But backsticks aren't deprecated and remain actively used by programers.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The OP wants the `$n`th line to be printed out, not the line containing the `$n`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I let you read the OP question I quoted before answering: "I am trying to use a variable to search a txt file, using that variable to find the line number."

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Anyway, I also add an answer for that but I'm not sure that's he really want (again it would be much more easier if the OP take the time to give the input file and the expected output).

Comment: Thank you everyone!! Wow. Hugely helpful responses. I was trying to use the date number to find the cooresponding text from that line in the txt file. Seems this was the solution from the last part of Idriss' response. Sorry I wasn't as clear about what I was looking for. 

#!/usr/bin/bash
dat="$(date +%j)"

arg=$(cat /home/adam/dailyverses.txt | sed -n "${dat}p")
 echo $arg

print("bible $arg")

Comment: No need to use `cat` @Adam, `sed` is enough (I've updated my answer again ^^ )

Comment: @IdrissNeumann, POSIX shells have **always** supported `$()`. It's only Bourne shells that predate the initial 1992 publication of POSIX.2 that required backticks. And since backticks introduce new semantics that change how quotes and backslashes are interpreted inside them (for the sake of nesting), using them adds a bunch of new complexity that folks learning modern syntax would otherwise have no reason to learn.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The backstick syntax is still often present on lots of scripts nowadays because there is lots of old sh developers that are still working on Linux right now (even on big companies like docker for example). And again, it's not clearly deprecated.  So that's way, I prefer to remain exhaustive even if I'm using the `$()` syntax every time.

Comment: To be clear: I still object to the "old POSIX shell" phrase as it implies a counterfactual; _no_ POSIX-compliant shell (ever since there first was a POSIX specification for the shell command language) has ever not supported `$()`. "pre-POSIX" shell would not warrant objection.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fair enough, you're right. I updated my answer with "old shell" instead.